# Serial.read() not decoding correctly

Tags: python, serialization, arduino

I have some python here that is trying to send numbers to an arduino via serial.

```
import serial
import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    lightBright = 0
    strversion = str(lightBright)
    ser.write(strversion.encode())
    while lightBright < 50:
        lightBright += 1
        print(lightBright)
        strversion = str(lightBright)
        ser.write(strversion.encode())
        time.sleep(0.03)
        if lightBright == 50:
            lightBright = 0
            strversion = str(lightBright)
            ser.write(strversion.encode())
            break
```

Here is the code I use to receive the serial:

```
int incomingByte;
int brightness = 0;
int parser = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(9, 0);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    int str = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(str);
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the Serial Monitor puts out incorrect numbers. I am looking to get 0-50. The output I get is:

48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
49
48
49
49
49
50
49
51
49
52
49
53
49
54
49
55
49
56
49
57
50
48
50
49
50
50
50
51
50
52
50
53
50
54
50
55
50
56
50
57
51
48
51
49
51
50
51
51
51
52
51
53
51
54
51
55
51
56
51
57
52
48
52
49
52
50
52
51
52
52
52
53
52
54
52
55
52
56
52
57
53
48
48

I have looked into upping the serial speed which also did not give me results I was looking for. I've also looked into sending these integers without making them a string, but that just gave me 0's in the monitor output. I am looking for the Serial Monitor to output numbers 1-50.

Comment: Serial.read return the ASCII value of the byte it reads, is that what you expect?

Comment: No. I'm expecting to see just the string. How do I go about decoding the ASCII value?

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect the integer value you should use [Serial.parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/) and not Serial.read() which return the ASCII value of the byte.